# Using custom variables in .ENV using Shopify CLI

Tags: reactjs, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I'm using the Shopify CLI to create an app which allows me to use Shopify Serve.

Whenever you run Shopify Serve it automatically rewrites the .ENV file and removes any custom variables added.  I'm trying to add a variable for MongoDB.

Can someone suggest a solution to either allow me to use the .ENV file to store the MongoDB details or an alternative solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shopify server only update your ngrok url in your .env file you can write your MongoURL in .env file and shopify server command change nothing expect ngrok url use it in server.js as

```
const mongoURL = process.env.MONGO_URL
```

Comment: They actually do erase it though.  I can watch it do it live.  If I add the variable to the .env file and run Shopify Serve it will erase the entire file and replace it with the shopify related entries.

Comment: are you working on online server like Heroku? if so then you must add all .env variables on your app setting in Heroku, or if you are other server than Heroku you should should see their method of adding .env variables..

Comment: no, during development. When you use the CLI you can enter shopify serve to automatically launch nodemon, ngrok, update app on partner site, and then launch the server.  It’s a great feature IMO.

Comment: Hy shannon, this happen because of new Shopify CLI Update. the same issue occur in 2019 update but later they fix it. hope so the Shopify team fix this issue also.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Good to know.  For now I'll continue to import what I need in a separate file and keep an eye out for it.

Comment: If you can help with this question I would be really appreciated.  I'm new to react/javascript and struggling to understand how things play together. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66854355/